# Variable in python not working, can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

Can someone assist me in fixing my code, I am new to python and learning the basics however I cannot figure out why I cannot get the "tax" section to print a value? even after following the tutorial step by step.

Full script:

```
################### Item Descriptions ###################

lovely_loveseat_description = "Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."
lovely_loveseat_price = 254.00

stylish_settee_description = "Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch. 29.50 inches high x 54.75 inches wide x 28 inches deep. Black."
stylish_settee_description = 180.50

luxurious_lamp_description = "Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Brown with cream shade."
luxurious_lamp_price = 52.15

################### Total Formulas ###################

sales_tax = int(.884)

customer_one_itemization = "Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."
customer_one_total = " "
customer_one_total += str(lovely_loveseat_price)
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax

################### Prints ###################

print("Customer One Items")
print(customer_one_itemization)
print("Customer One Total")
print(customer_one_total)
print("Customer tax Total")
print(customer_one_tax)
```

I get the following in the output:

```
Customer One Items
Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white.
Customer One Total
 254.0
Customer tax Total
(THIS SHOULD PRINT THE TAX TOTAL)
```

Comment: `int(.884)` is zero. So `sales_tax` is zero. `customer_one_total` is a string. If you multiple a string by zero you get an empty string. I imagine the tutorial did something different.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the answer, the question stated Define the variable "sales_tax" and set it equal to .088. That’s 8.8%.

Does this clear anything up?

Comment: If you want to set sales_tax to .088 then you can just do `sales_tax = .088`. After than you still have the problem that `customer_one_total` is a string; and I'm not sure why you did that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
################### Item Descriptions ###################

lovely_loveseat_description = "Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."
lovely_loveseat_price = 254.00

stylish_settee_description = "Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch. 29.50 inches high x 54.75 inches wide x 28 inches deep. Black."
stylish_settee_description = 180.50

luxurious_lamp_description = "Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Brown with cream shade."
luxurious_lamp_price = 52.15

################### Total Formulas ###################

sales_tax = .088

customer_one_itemization = "Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."
customer_one_total = lovely_loveseat_price
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax

################### Prints ###################

print("Customer One Items")
print(customer_one_itemization)
print("Customer One Total")
print(customer_one_total)
print("Customer tax Total")
print(customer_one_tax)
```

Output:

```
Customer One Items
Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white.
Customer One Total
254.0
Customer tax Total
22.352
```

Your code had several errors that I had to fix:

- You initialize `customer_one_total` by setting it equal to `""`
- `lovely_loveseat_price` is added to `customer_one_total` as a `str`
- `sales_tax` should not be set to `int(.884)` which is just zero. According to your comment you want it to be `.088`

Comment: Thank you! @Catasaurus, this makes far more sense than the tutorial directions. I appreciate the help.